# Find and replace to standardize whitespace

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have about 50 templates, and I would like to standardize whitespace on variables as follows --

```
Inputs: {{variable}}, {{ something  }}, {{  test  }}, etc.
Output: {{ variable }}, {{ something }}, {{ test }} # one space within inner bracket
```

How would I do this find and replace to all files within `myproject/templates` ? Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a question for superuser? that is if you must use find and replace instead of a regular expressions.

Comment: do you literally mean the string `variable`, or can anything be between `{{` and `}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find /myproject/templates -type f | xargs sed -i 's/{{\s*\(\S*\)\s*}}/{{ \1 }}/g'`

Translation:

`find /myprojects/templates -type f` will find all items in `/myproject/templates` that are regular files (as opposed to symlinks or directories).

`xargs sed -i s/FIND/REPLACE/g'` will execute `sed` to edit each file in place (that is, it will replace the contents of the file with the edited version).  It will search for the pattern `FIND` and replace it with `REPLACE` globally (that is, everywhere it appears on the line).

The components of the `FIND` pattern:

`{{\s*` = two open-braces followed by zero or more whitespace characters

`\(\S*\)` = any *non*-whitespace characters.  (This means your variable names cannot contain internal spaces.)  The escaped parens will save those characters (which are your variable names) for use in the `REPLACE` pattern.

`\s*}}` = zero or more whitespace characters followed by two close-braces.

The components of the `REPLACE` pattern are two open-braces, a single space, the variable name we saved using `\(\S*\)`, another space, and the two close-braces.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Gosh, all you people with a non-POSIX `sed`. :( My `sed` doesn’t do `-i` and it doesn’t do `\s` and `\S`.  But you can replace `sed -i` with `perl -i -pe` and it will just work.  It will also work on Unicode if you ask it nicely.

Comment: what if there are more than one variable in the same line?

Comment: tchrist: to be POSIX-compliant, you may be able to use the (longer) equivalents here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html.  And instead of `find` you can use a `for` loop that creates a new version of each file.  But I tend to take advantage of the tools at hand, especially for one-time tasks.

Comment: F.C.: you'd have to replace `\S` with something more clever than I can come up with at the moment.  Anyone up to the challenge?